# hid one div if another is showing else the opposite?

Tags: javascript

im trying to keep div 1 hidden if div 2 is on display, but when div 2 is hidden i want div 1 to show. im trying to do this in javascript but its not working for me :(

can someone please show me where im going wrong thanks.

```
<script>
 $(".profile-banner2").hide();
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if ($('.infobox-profile').is(":visible")) {
             $(".profile-banner2").hide();

              } else if ($('.infobox-profile').is(":hidden")) {
            $('.profile-banner2').show();

        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second condition include `$(".profile-banner1").hide()`?

Comment: 1) you need an event like a click or so and 2) do not put any statements that access Dom objects outside your document.ready 3) you need toggle

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<div id="div1"> this is first div </div>
<div style="display:none"> this is second div</div>

<input type="submit" value="toggle" id="toggle"/>
```

and the script:

```
$(function(){
    $("#toggle").click(function(){
    $("div").toggle();
    });

});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UuJPw/1/)

---

**EDIT**

check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UuJPw/2/),which works if the anywhere in the html is clicked

Comment: thanks but i wanted it as a document ready function not as a click

Comment: If you put that in document ready then you will only see `this is second div`